# Select multiple scalar values as multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I would need a nice way to select a set of values as rows.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
mysql> select 1 as v union select 2;
+---+
| v |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Is there a better way to write such a query?**

The list of values is known at query generation time.

Comment: This question is hard to answer without knowing your real use-case. For example: Are the values you want to have always constant? Will it always be the same number of values?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is "no".

Comment: Yes, the list of values is constant, or at least known at query generation time.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth is there anything else that's not clear? I need a static list of values as a subselect (preferable). I could also create a temp table and join/query that, but that would complicate the program logic, I'd thus like to more-or-less put a "static temp table" into a select/subquery.

Comment: Check [this SP](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=4), it lets you split a string into multiple rows.

Comment: a better way would be `select 1 as v union all select 2;`.   But only if you do want duplicate when doing: select 42 as v union select 42;

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2)) AS x;
```